# Continue Completable after doOnComplete Android

Tags: android, rx-java

I am new in RX Java and I have a issue.I have a `completable` and want to continue my operations after I got a value and did some actions in one of the steps of emmition.

```
 if (mIsCopy) {
            completable = AppManagers.getContentManager().completeCopy(mContent).toCompletable().andThen(completable).doOnComplete(() -> {
                   createThumbnailsForNewContent(mContent); //I want this to be happen before completable.cache();
            });
        }

        completable = completable.cache();

        completable.subscribe(new SimpleCompletableSubscriber() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                TypeUtil.empty(mNewTags);
                mOriginalSubmitToUsers.clear();
                mOriginalSubmitToUsers.addAll(mSubmitToUsers);
                mOriginalSubmitToGroups.clear();
                mOriginalSubmitToGroups.addAll(mSubmitToGroups);
                mOriginalSubmitToChannels.clear();
                mOriginalSubmitToChannels.addAll(mSubmitToChannels);
                mOriginalSubmitToRelationships.clear();
                mOriginalSubmitToRelationships.addAll(mSubmitToRelationships);
                mIsCopy = false;
            }
```

`createThumbnailsForNewContent(mContent);` returns completable,thx in advance.

```
   public Single<Long> completeCopy(final Content copiedContent) {
        return Single.fromCallable(new Callable<Long>() {
            @Override
            public Long call() throws Exception {
                if (!copiedContent.isLocalCopy() || copiedContent.getId() != null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Content passed must be an unsaved local copy.");
                }

                if (getDBManager().insertOrUpdateContent(copiedContent)) {
                    if (copiedContent.getCopiedFromCloudID() != null && copiedContent.getCopiedFromCloudID() > 0) {
                        AppManagers.getAppContext()
                                .getRequestQueue()
                                .forRequest(new InitiateCopyRequest(AppUserData.shared.getAccessKey(),
                                                                    copiedContent.getCopiedFromCloudID()))
                                .withPriority(RequestQueue.Priority.UPDATE)
                                .attachLocalID(copiedContent.getId())
                                .enqueue();
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new ErrorCodeException(ErrorCodes.UPDATE_CONTENT_FAILED);
                }

                return copiedContent.getId();

            }
        }).subscribeOn(getIOScheduler());
    }
```

Comment: `continue my operations` . Do you mean keep the subscription alive ?

Comment: @agent_hunt I want when `onComplete` is triggerd  `createThumbnailsForNewContent(mContent);` would already be finished

Comment: Could you please provide more info on what are you trying to do ? From what I can see if a copy is in progress you are chaining the previous completable to next one and subscribe again on this one.

Comment: after `completeCopy(mContent)` I can get the new mContent and want to  createThumbnails for that content and `createThumbnailsForNewContent(mContent);` is async so my OnComplete is triggered before my thumbnails are generated

Comment: Dont you need to wait for onComplete/onError of `completeCopy(mContent).toCompletable()` ?  to  be certain that it is completed ? Can you post the source of `AppManagers.getContentManager().completeCopy(mContent)` . Where is the new `mContent` coming from ?  Would it better if you used different variables say `completable1` `completable2` ?

Comment: @agent_hunt yes I need to wait for  ` onComplete/onError of completeCopy(mContent).toCompletable()` and the after that mContent already got `id ` so I can generate thumbnails for that content.Also I edited the answer,and can you please tell me how can I chain completable1 and completable2,I guess one of them should be for ` createThumbnailsForNewContent(mContent);` right?

Comment: What is the value of the variable `completable` before this code ```completable = AppManagers.getContentManager().completeCopy(mContent).toCompletable().andThen(completable).doOnComplete(() -> {
                   createThumbnailsForNewContent(mContent); //I want this to be happen before completable.cache();
            });``` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169355/discussion-between-laurent-koscielny-and-agent-hunt).

Answer (score 0):

Don't really get the problem, but according to your code it seems that the method `createThumbnailsForNewContent` is never executed. That's because `doOnComplete` accepts as param an `Action` (this is a `Runnable` but allows throwing checked exceptions).

If you want to execute `createThumbnailsForNewContent` once the previous `Completable` is completed, you have to use the operator `andThen(CompletableSource next)`.